# How Redux Toolkit extra reducers execute conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

With redux-toolkit everything works good. But even when there is an error on fetching data `dismissAll` action still works and I cannot stop it to execute.

```
import { createEntityAdapter, createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import firebaseService from 'app/services/firebaseService';

export const dismissAll = createAsyncThunk('notificationPanel/data/dismissAll', async (params, { getState }) => {
    const { user } = getState().auth;
    try {
        await firebaseService.realtimeDB.ref(`notifications/${user.uid}/alerts`).remove();
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

const notificationsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({});

const initialState = notificationsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const {
    selectAll: selectNotifications,
    selectById: selectNotificationsById
} = notificationsAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.notificationPanel.data);

const dataSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'notificationPanel/data',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addNotification: (state, action) => notificationsAdapter.addOne(state, action.payload)
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [getNotifications.fulfilled]: (state, action) => notificationsAdapter.addMany(state, action.payload),
        [dismissItem.fulfilled]: (state, action) => notificationsAdapter.removeOne,
        [dismissAll.fulfilled]: (state, action) => notificationsAdapter.removeAll
    }
});
```

I tried something like:

```
[dismissAll.fulfilled]: (state, action) => { 
   if (action.payload === true) notificationsAdapter.removeAll 
}
```

But it returns error using like that.

How can I execute it conditionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an error, `createAsyncThunk` is not gonna pick it up if you already handle it - because from the perspective of `createAsyncThunk` there is no error then.

Either remove your `try..catch` wrapping, or `throw error` within your `catch` block to re-throw the error. `cAT` will then stop to dispatch a fulfilled action in that case and dispatch a rejected action instead.